# mapstruct wrapper type and generics

Tags: java, wrapper, mapstruct

I am trying to map `JsonNullable<List<ChildRequestTO>` to `Nullable<List<ChildRequestDO>>` (see full code below) with *mapstruct 1.4.2.Final* and I am facing the following error: `error: Nullable<List<ChildRequestDO>> does not have an accessible constructor.` If I add a constructor for `Nullable` like

```java
    public Nullable(T value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.isPresent = true;
    }
```

then I get the following error `error: Unmapped target property: "value". Mapping from property "JsonNullable<List<ChildRequestTO>> products" to "Nullable<List<ChildRequestDO>> products".`

*How do I map complex wrapped types in a generic way?*

The following mapping code (part of `ChildRequestMapper` class and applied in `ObjectRequestMapper`) solves the problem but I want to solve it in a more generic way:

```java
    @Named("mappingHelper")
    default Nullable<List<ChildRequestDO>> customMapToDOs(JsonNullable<List<ChildRequestTO>> input) {
        if (JsonNullable.undefined().equals(input)) {
            return Nullable.undefined();
        }
        if (input.get() == null) {
            return Nullable.of(null);
        }
        var output= input.get()
                .stream()
                .map(this::mapToDO)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return Nullable.of(output);
    }
```

Changing the `NullableMapper` to the code below does not work/compile because I do not know how to tell mapstruct to look for the appropriate mapper to map from `T` to `X`.

```java
    public static <T, X> Nullable<X> jsonNullableToNullable(JsonNullable<T> jsonNullable) {
        if (jsonNullable.isPresent()) {
            return Nullable.of(jsonNullable.get());
        }
        return Nullable.undefined();
    }
```

**Full code:**

```java
@Mapper(
        unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.ERROR,
        uses = {ChildRequestMapper.class, NullableMapper.class}
)
public interface ObjectRequestMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "slots", source = "slots", qualifiedByName = "mapToSlotDOs")
    ModifyObjectRequestDO mapToDO(ModifyObjectRequestTO input);
}
```

```java
@Mapper(unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.ERROR)
public interface ChildRequestMapper {

    ChildRequestDO mapToDO(ChildRequestTO input);
}
```

```java
public class NullableMapper {

    public static <T> Nullable<T> jsonNullableToNullable(JsonNullable<T> jsonNullable) {
        if (jsonNullable.isPresent()) {
            return Nullable.of(jsonNullable.get());
        }
        return Nullable.undefined();
    }
}
```

```java
public class ModifyObjectRequestTO {

    private JsonNullable<String> name = JsonNullable.undefined();
    private JsonNullable<List<ChildRequestTO>> children = JsonNullable.undefined();

}
```

```java
public class ModifyObjectRequestDO {

    private Nullable<String> name = Nullable.undefined();
    private Nullable<List<ChildRequestDO>> children = Nullable.undefined();

}
```

```java
public class Nullable<T> {

    private static final Nullable<?> UNDEFINED = new Nullable<>(null, false);

    private final T value;

    private final boolean isPresent;

    private Nullable(T value, boolean isPresent) {
        this.value = value;
        this.isPresent = isPresent;
    }

    public static <T> Nullable<T> undefined() {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Nullable<T> t = (Nullable<T>) UNDEFINED;
        return t;
    }

    public static <T> Nullable<T> of(T value) {
        return new Nullable<T>(value, true);
    }

    public T get() {
        if (!isPresent) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("Value is undefined");
        }
        return value;
    }

    public boolean isPresent() {
        return isPresent;
    }

}
```

Comment: Which version of MapStruct are you using?

Comment: @Filip 1.4.2.Final

Comment: This seems like a bug. I thought that we did some fixes for this in 1.4.2.Final, but it was for something else apparently. We are doing some more improvements in the way we handle generics. Can you please create an issue in our issue tracker?

Comment: @Filip I opened an issue https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/2377